# Celery - errno 111 connection refused

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

My celery tasks stops getting executed in between. My rabbitmq stops in between and then I need to restart it manually. Last time(15-16 hours back), similar problem occurred, I did the following (manually), and it started working again.

I reinstalled the rabbitmq and then it started working again.

`sudo apt-get --purge remove raabitmq-server`

`sudo apt-get install raabitmq-server`

Now it is again showing `

```
Celery - errno 111 connection refused
```

Following is my config.

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Oslo'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong?

How should I rectify it?

**Part2**

Also, I've multiple queues. I can run it within the project directory, but when demonizing, the workers dont take task. I still need to start the celery workers manually. How can I demozize it?

Here is my celerd conf.

```
# Name of nodes to start, here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3 w4"


CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/var/www/fractal/parser-quicklook/"

# Python interpreter from environment, if using virtualenv
#ENV_PYTHON="/somewhere/.virtualenvs/MyProject/bin/python"

# How to call "manage.py celeryd_multi"
#CELERYD_MULTI="/usr/local/bin/celeryd-multi"

# How to call "manage.py celeryctl"
#CELERYCTL="/usr/local/bin/celeryctl"

#CELERYBEAT="/usr/local/bin/celerybeat"

# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8  -Q BBC,BGR,FASTCOMPANY,Firstpost,Guardian,IBNLIVE,LIVEMINT,Mashable,NDTV,Pandodaily,Reuters,TNW,TheHindu,ZEENEWS "

# Name of the celery config module, don't change this.
CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#CELERYD_USER="nobody"
#CELERYD_GROUP="nobody"

# Set any other env vars here too!
PROJET_ENV="PRODUCTION"

# Name of the projects settings module.
# in this case is just settings and not the full path because it will change the dir to
# the project folder first.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

Celeryconfig is already provided in part1.

Here is my proj directory structure.

```
project
|-- main.py
|-- project
|   |-- celeryconfig.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|-- tasks.py
```

**How can I demonize with the Queues?** I have provided the queues in `CELERYD_OPTS` as well.

Is there a way in which we can dynamically demonize the number of queues in the celery? For eg:- we have `CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True` for creating the missing queues. Is there something similar to daemonize the celery queues?

Comment: did you update the rabbitmq server database after you brought it up again ?
YOu need to add users vhost and set permissions before you can connect celery using the same user.

`sudo rabbitmqtcl add_user USERNAME PASSWORD`
`sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost VHOST_NAME`
`sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p VHOST_NAME USERNAME ".*" ".*" ".*"`

Comment: Also how does your celery app configuration element BROKER_URL looks like ?

Comment: I'm not able to create a user. Whenever I try to create one, it throws up an error saying `Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@li732-193': nodedown`. Upon looking at the `sudo service rabbitmq-server status` it shows the same error.

Comment: I restarted the celery-server and created the user and add the permissions. Then gave a restart to the rabbit-server.  After doing all this, I checked the celery status and it still shows the same error. Connection refused.

Comment: I would suggest you to stop the rabbitmq service before you change the database `sudo rabbitmqctl stop` chage the database by the above commands and then run the service in the background `sudo rabbitmq-server –detached`

Comment: My BROKER_URL is `BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'`

Comment: How does your celery app configuration look like what is your BROKER_URL ? Your BORKER_URL seems to be wrong. Also check the status of rabbitmq service

Comment: rabbitmq status is fine. and my brokerurl setting in the config file is set as `BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'`

Comment: `BROKER_URL='amqp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOSTNAME:5672/VHOST_NAME',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='amqp',
    CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True`

5672 is the default port for rabbitmq

Comment: The following links have all the information
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html
transport://userid:password@hostname:port/virtual_host

Comment: is the HOSTNAME = localhost? Please confirm . Thanks

Comment: hostname is the hostname or ipaddress of the system running rabbitmq service, localhost should work, but I have not tested it myself

Comment: I set my broker url as per your instructions. But still the same error upon ` celery status`. connection refused

Comment: Make sure firewall is not blocking the connection, you can shut it off by `sudo service iptables stop`,make sure the rabbitmq process is running `ps aux | grep rabbitmq` and a listening socket is up `lsof -p PID`make sure the service is running `sudo rabbitmqctl status` `sudo rabbitmqctl list_users` `sudo rabbitmqctl list_vhosts` `sudo rabbitmqctl list_permissions` please look and provide the above command output and check the logs, wireshark capture can also point to the problem

Comment: How did you start your celery worker?

Comment: The main question is everything was working fine 2 hours before, and suddenly it has stop connecting.

Comment: I was finally able to fix it. `sudo apt-get --purge remove raabitmq-server` and `sudo apt-get install raabitmq-server`. This fixed it,.

Comment: Now how can I daemonize the celery with multiple queues (Part2 of the question). ?? Any idea

Comment: Celery has demonizing scrpits for workers that comes with the distribution http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html

Comment: Now it's again not able to connect. Why I'm getting this error again and again?

Comment: Looks like the number of connections exceeding limit problem. Have you set the broker pool limit correctly?

Answer (score 6):

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

This solved by adding it to `__init__.py` file of project root folder

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you fixed this already, but from the look of it, seems you have a bunch of problems.

first and foremost, check if your RabbitMQ server has troubles staying up for some reason.

- You should start with basic health checks (e.g. CPU, processes and memory),
- double check your installation followed their guide here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html
- then check Rabbit's logfiles, their locations listed here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html
- or any other OS log file that might point you to the right direction (e.g. `/var/log/syslog` might be a good place to start). You don't say anything about your server OS, but assuming it's Debian/Ubuntu because you mention apt-get, here's a list of OS log locations that might help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles

also, be sure that your RabbitMQ server has been configured with the correct credentials and allow access from your worker's location (e.g. enable connections other than loopback users): here's what you need to do: https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

then, check you have configured your worker with the correct authentication credentials, a full URL should look similar to the following (where user must be granted access to the specific virtualhost, it's quite easy to configure it via the RabbitMQ management interface https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html):

`BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:pass@host:port/virtualhost'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://user:pass@host:port/virtualhost'`

and finally, try to traceback the exception in python, that should hopefully give you some additional information about the error

hth

p.s. re. demonizing your celery worker, @budulianin answer is spot on!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I demozize it?

Usually, I use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) for this purpose.

Here config example:

```
[program:celery]
command=/home/my_project/.virtualenvs/my_project/bin/celery worker
    -A my_project.project.celery_app.celery_app
    -n worker-%(process_num)s
    --concurrency=4
    --statedb=/tmp/%(process_num)s.state
    -l INFO

environment=MY_SETTINGS='/etc/my_settings.py'
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs_start=1
numprocs=4
user=user_name
directory=/home/my_project
stdout_logfile=/var/log/my_project/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/my_project/celery_err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
killasgroup=true
priority=998
```

BTW, [CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-create-missing-queues) enabled by default.